# Contour and/or Corner plots for MCMC for a 2d distribution

Tags: python, contour

Can anyone help with Python plt.contour()? I am trying to make a contour plot with 4 different over-plots to see the relation between x, and y values for my MCMC function I ran 4 different times for a 2d gaussian function I coded up. I will take any advice on using corner.corner() for my data if you feel that's easier. [See picture for code of MCMC, and error when trying to use plt.contour()]  Thanks in advance. Here is the distribution code:

```
### 2d Distribution function 
## inputs (xStep, mean1,stdDeviation1, mean2,stdDeviation2, amplitude1, amplitude2)
def p(x,y, mu1=1,sgmx=1, mu2=1,sgmy=1, amp1=1):
    p2d = amp1*(1/(2*np.pi*sgmx*sgmy))*np.exp(-((((x-mu1)**2)/(2*sgmx**2))+(((y-mu2)**2)/(2*sgmy**2)))) 
return p2d
```

And I tried to use plt.contour() with no luck

```
plt.contour(x1, y1, pvs1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uipwl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnr5a.png)

Answer (score 0):

From https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html

The last argument, `Z` in their notation,  `pvs1` in your notation, **has to be 2D** (just look at the error you receive, but also in the docu).

Maybe try to reshape your `pvs1` into a 2D np.array, to simulate what `np.meshgrid` would actually do? Would be good to look into that as well.